# Best Way to Project Properties of Two Resources Into a Set of String

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

What is the best way to add properties of multiple resource instances into a Set of String.

The resource below may contain 1-many instances.

```
resource aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_bronze{}
```

The resource below may contain 1-many instances.

```
resource aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_silver{}
```

I would like to retrieve a property named `replication_instance_id` from all instances of both of the resources above and put it in a Set of String.

It seems workable to do that with each instance. Is there a better way to do this and combine the two resources in the output?

```
locals {

  target_instance_ids = toset(flatten([
    for i in aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_silver : [      
        replication_instance_id 
      ]
    ]   
  ]))

}
```

Comment: Just spitballing here, but have you tried something like `toset(concat(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_bronze[*].id, aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_silver[*].id))`? Without more information I am unsure exactly if that would work, but it seems close regardless.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - Was unaware of the [*] construct, will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Splat Expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) and the [`setunion()` Function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setunion) to get the desired result:

```
locals {
  target_instance_ids = setunion(
    aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_bronze[*].replication_instance_id,
    aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instances_silver[*].replication_instance_id,
  )
}
```

A more detailed example can be found [here](https://www.terraformbyexample.com/splat/).

Comment: That looks much cleaner than the setunion(toset(flatten([])), toset(flatten([]))) thing that I came up with. Thanks for your help.